# HTML Perl update button with SQL problem

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, perl, button

I'm trying to create a sort of update button, when a user clicks on a HTML Perl button it asks for confirmation (yes/no).

If the user clicks "Yes" it runs a SQL script then returns a pop-up (JavaScript) saying operation successful (or not).

The SQL code is creating a backup table then copying the current values stored in the database to this backup table, so no screen refresh is necessary. The complete and functioning code is provided below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backup_tab_right_mapping
    LIKE tab_right_mapping;
DELETE FROM backup_tab_right_mapping
    WHERE group_id = "1"
    AND role_id = "1";
INSERT INTO backup_tab_right_mapping
SELECT * FROM tab_right_mapping
    WHERE group_id = "1"
    AND role_id = "1";
```

However I dont want to use PHP, I'm looking for a Sub solution.

Thanks for your time and any help you can provide XD

*EDIT: Project requirements only allow me to use perl, HTML and JavaScript.*

Comment: What do you mean by "Sub" solution, do you want a stored procedure to perform the backup? Also, you don't have to issue the `DELETE` after the `CREATE` as you have created an empty table.

Comment: @Tony The `DELETE` is there because it only creates the table IF it is doesn't exist, otherwise it will use the existing table. If the values already exist, they need to be deleted. When I say `Sub` I mean encased within a Perl Sub - that is of course if that is possible for what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works also without JavaScript. You need to add more client-side error-checking in case the program aborts abnormally.

To follow best practice, store the database credentials outside the program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head><title />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" />
</head><body><form action="backup-table" method="POST"><input type="submit" /></form>
<script>
$('form').submit(function() {
    if (confirm('Backup table?')) {
        $.post("backup-table", function(data) {
            alert($(data).text());
        });
        return false;
    };
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use CGI qw();
use DBI qw();

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:…', '…username…', '…password…', {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1,});

for my $sql (
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backup_tab_right_mapping
        LIKE tab_right_mapping;',
    'DELETE FROM backup_tab_right_mapping
        WHERE group_id = "1"
        AND role_id = "1";',
    'INSERT INTO backup_tab_right_mapping
    SELECT * FROM tab_right_mapping
        WHERE group_id = "1"
        AND role_id = "1";',
) {
    $dbh->do($sql);
}

my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header('application/xhtml+xml');
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head><title /></head>
<body><p>Backup complete</p></body></html>';
```

Comment: thanks for that, I'll try tomorrow and let you know, its finishing time now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do it this way. 
But I would do it

- Create one script which does all the copy stuff keep it on server.
- Create a web page with *XMLHttpRequest* in its submit button which inturn will be calling the original script doing the sql operation.
- Capture the *responseText* response and print the message on your page using js, or put one alert box there.

Simpler solution is:

- Create a script on server which has the submit button and one hidden input which can tell about the next operation
- based on the hidden parameter call your sub available in same script as sub.
- capture the response and do what ever java script magic you want to do.
  If you need I can provide a sample too for second approach.

Comment: The purpose is to allow an admin user to backup or restore (code not shown) user privileges for a website, where the rights are stored in the database. The only reason I ask for it to be kept in perl is because I have to keep it simple - project requirements only allow me to use languages supported within the company (perl, HTML and JavaScript). So I am simply looking for a way to somehow run this query from a website, with a warning before, and a confirmation afterwards. other easier ways are of course welcome. Thanks,